# How do I find the ML model referenced in a specific paper when the authors don't provide it?

Tags: publications, research-process, reproducible-research

I'm trying to locate the architecture of an LSTM neural network as described [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1711/1711.10192.pdf), but the authors don't provide a repository for other academics.

From arXiv, I see more than a dozen other researchers have referenced this paper and specifically utilized the same model architecture but it's unclear to me how they got access to the python source code. I've tried emailing some researchers but none of them have responded. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked all those papers and all the ones those papers reference? They must have got, or worked out, that architecture.

Comment: Why not ask them directly? Nothing to lose.

Comment: I already asked the original researchers if I could use their model. They didn't respond so they must be busy!

Comment: How long ago did you contact them? I would wait for, like, 7-10 days before assuming that they ignored me.

Comment: It is also possible that the papers that cited this reimplemented the model, or at least one of them did.